# Having trouble calculating prices

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a booking form in C#, where a user can select multiple tickets for one or more attraction site. They can also add a promotion code for a 10% discount on the total price if the code contains an "X". I'm having trouble with calculating the total price before the promotion discount can be taken away. I thought I could make the default value of each attraction "0" so when the individual prices are added for dblPrice, but that doesn't work.

Here's what I have so far -

```
        //declared variables
        double dblPrice;
        double dblDiscount;
        double dblRollprice, dblWaterprice, dblKidsprice, dblLiveprice, dblActionprice, dblThrillprice, dbl4dprice;
        double dblTotalprice;
        string strRollquantity, strWaterquantity, strKidsquantity, strLivequantity, strActionquantity, strThrillquantity, str4dquantity;
        int intWaterquantity, intRollquantity, intKidsquantity, intLivequantity, intActionquantity, intThrillquantity, int4dquantity;
        string strPromocode;


        strPromocode = txtPromocode.Text;
        strRollquantity = txtRollquantity.Text;
        strWaterquantity = txtWaterquantity.Text;
        strKidsquantity = txtKidsquantity.Text;
        strLivequantity = txtLivequantity.Text;
        strActionquantity = txtActionquantity.Text;
        strThrillquantity = txtThrillquantity.Text;
        str4dquantity = txt4dquantity.Text;

        int.TryParse(strRollquantity, out intRollquantity);
        int.TryParse(strWaterquantity, out intWaterquantity);
        int.TryParse(strKidsquantity, out intKidsquantity);
        int.TryParse(strLivequantity, out intLivequantity);
        int.TryParse(strActionquantity, out intActionquantity);
        int.TryParse(strThrillquantity, out intThrillquantity);
        int.TryParse(str4dquantity, out int4dquantity);


        dblRollprice = 15.00;
        dblWaterprice = 15.00;
        dblActionprice = 15.00;
        dblKidsprice = 15.00;
        dblLiveprice = 15.00;
        dbl4dprice = 15.00;
        dblThrillprice = 15.00;


        if (chkRoll.Checked)
        {
            dblRollprice = dblRollprice * intRollquantity;
        }

        if (chkWater.Checked)
        {
            dblWaterprice = dblWaterprice * intWaterquantity;
        }

        if (chkKids.Checked)
        {
            dblKidsprice = 15.00 * intKidsquantity;
        }

        if (chkLive.Checked)
        {
            dblLiveprice = 15.00 * intLivequantity;
        }

        if (chkAction.Checked)
        {
            dblActionprice = 15.00 * intActionquantity;
        }

        if (chkThrill.Checked)
        {
            dblThrillprice = 15.00 * intThrillquantity;
        }

        if (chk4d.Checked)
        {
            dbl4dprice = 15.00 * int4dquantity;
        }

        dblPrice = dblRollprice + dblWaterprice + dblThrillprice + dblLiveprice + dblActionprice + dbl4dprice + dblKidsprice;


        if (strPromocode == "X")
        {
            dblDiscount = dblPrice / 100 * 10;
            dblTotalprice = dblPrice - dblDiscount;
            Response.Write("Price is: " + dblTotalprice + "<br />");
        }
```

Comment: OP, please be sure of the language you are using. I saw C++ in the description so fixed the tag, but looking more closely I realise it's C#.

Comment: Please also define what "doesn't work" means so that we don't have to try and guess what's wrong.

Comment: So when I select one ticket for an Action ride for example, and enter "X" for the promo code, it adds all of the site attraction prices together (105) and then takes 10% away - so the result is 94.5. It should instead just calculate 10% off of 15.00 and then output that.

Comment: I don't know how else to say this: you programmed your logic incorrectly then.  It clearly applies the discount _after_ summing all the prices, and applies it to the sum `dblPrice` instead of an individual price.  If you want to only apply the discount to one of the prices, you have to move your `if (strPromocode == "X")` logic above your price sum, and inside the `if`, apply 10% to only which individual price you want the discount on, such as to `dblRollprice`.  Then the sum for `dblPrice` will work out.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is actually apply the discount to a Totalprice value of any attractions the user selects. So they can select 2 Action tickets, 3 Roll tickets etc. - then it would calculate the total price of that and the discount is then taken off it, and finally output the result.